# Docker error from CMD command prompt: Something went wrong running an SSH Command

Tags: windows, ssh, docker, cmd, installation

I am using the following tutorial to install TensorFlow on my Windows machine, using Docker: http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/

1. I installed Docker
2. I opened quickstart terminal
3. I set up a new virtual box "vdocker"
4. From within quickstart terminal, I ran

   `docker-machine ls` and got:

   ```
   NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
   default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
   vdocker   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
   ```
5. I opened up a command prompt from Windows Start menu (first as a non-administrator, and later as administrator), and when I do

   `docker-machine ls`

   I get the following:

   [image]

In particular, I get stuck on this step of the tutorial I included above:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd vdocker') DO %i
```

I cannot run the above in CMD successfully.

I found online solutions that say to regenerate certificates, remove default, re-create default and I tried them, with no luck. Hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> In particular, I get stuck on this step of the tutorial I included above:
>
> ```
> FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd vdocker') DO %i
> ```

That is not the command you show in the screenshot. There, the path has spaces in it, which causes the initial `C:\Program` do be passed to `DO %i`. That is, it first tries to execute `DO C:\Program` which is not an executable.

I am assuming the other problems are also related to the fact that the installation directory name contains spaces.